# docusign for custom modules in sugarcrm 7.5.0.1

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js, sugarcrm, docusignapi

I need to send an Order Details via custom PDF to a Contact's Email Id where Order is my custom module. I want to use DocuSign Integration for sending PDF documents in SugarCRM. But by default Docusign provides facility to send documents from only Opportunity, Account, Contract, or Quote modules.
How can I send custom PDFs with DocuSign Integration from a custom module in sugarcrm 7.5.0.1?

Comment: Do you have any existing code that can be of use here?

Comment: Hi Bono,No I am new to SugarCRM and Docusign

Answer (score 0):

SugarCRM owns their integration with DocuSign, not DocuSign.  If there are issues with the integration or you need support for it you would have to contact SugarCRM support or follow up with them through other means.